# loopback mysql connector and InnoDB 767 byte error

Tags: mysql, innodb, loopbackjs

Hi I'm currently using loopback, mysql and amazon AWS for web development

amazon AWS(amazon linux) is for deploy and for development, i'm using mac(el capitan).

there was problem with loopback mysql connector. the default varchar length for string was 512 so when I try to deploy it into AWS,

InnoDB generated error that column can't not be longer than 767 byte.

I fixed by changing lib/migrate.js in mysql connector.

but I still have question that why InnoDB in my local(mac) didn't generate any error.

before fix, mysql table column in my local had same varchar length 512.

my local pc and aws had same settings. (InnoDB, UTF-8).

have any idea why my local environment didn't generate any error?

- for those who have same error, you can modify node_modules/loopback_mysql_connector_lib/migrate.js

Comment: I that an IP address?  Only need 39 characters, and don't need utf8.

Comment: if loopback's default table attribute type is string. mysql connector interpret it as varchar(512)..

Comment: The problem is with "512" -- that is too big for indexing.  Or with "utf8"; can it be changed to "ascii" for this one column?

Comment: actually that problem is solved by modifying migrate.js file just forcing not to make 512 length column. i don't know about ascii. question is why it didn't have any error on local computer(mac)

Comment: A newer version of MySQL changed some defaults, thereby avoiding the problem.

Comment: thank you!! so MySQL version was the problem!